# Python: how to rename file in python?

Tags: python, rename

I have a file in a folder called `rain2014-01-01.dat` and want to rename it as `rain201401.dat`

First I check if find the file;

```
import os
path = "./mypath"
string = "rain2014-01-01.dat"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(string):
        print (filename)
```

which returns

```
rain2013-01-01.dat
```

Then I try to rename it

```
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(string):
        stringnew = 'rain%d%d.dat'%(year,i)
        os.rename(string,stringnew)
```

which returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-709ba44fed3d> in <module>()
      7     if filename.endswith(string):
      8         stringnew = 'rain%d%d.dat'%(year,i)
----> 9         os.rename(string,stringnew)
     10         print (filename)

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: You realize that `rain2014-01-01.dat` is not `mypath/rain2014-01-01.dat`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you got the file from `os.listdir('mypath')`, its full name is `mypath/rain2014-01-01.dat`, not `rain2014-01-01.dat`.

If the directory name is not prefixed, and no file with the same name exists in the current directory, the error given is entirely to be expected.

Use `os.path.join('mypath', string)` or `os.path.join('mypath', stringnew)` to get names relative to `mypath`.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` only returns the filename, not the full path. Use `glob` instead, so you can use patterns:

```
import glob
pattern = "./mypath/*rain2014-01-01.dat"
for filename in glob.iglob(pattern):
    stringnew = 'rain%d%d.dat' % (year, i)
    os.rename(string,stringnew)
```